# Importing data from spreadsheet to Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spreadsheet

I am new to Neo4j.I downloaded the software from www.neo4j.org and I was able to create the Movie graph which came with the download.

Now I am trying to export data from spreadsheet into Neo4j.[Here](http://blog.neo4j.org/2013/03/importing-data-into-neo4j-spreadsheet.html) is the procedure I am following

I was stuck at the last step - THEN EXECUTE THE FOLLOWING COMMAND, making sure that Neo4j is NOT running:

```
cat import.txt | <neo4j directory>/bin/neo4j-shell -config conf/neo4j.properties -path     <neo4j directory>/data/graph.db
```

I am not sure where to find neo4j-shell and conf/neo4j.properties.I don't have these folders in my download.Then I found that I have to download ne04j-community-2.0.1-windows.

I downloaded it and I see neo4j-shell and also conf/neo4j.properties.Now that I have all the things requires to execute the above statement, I am not sure where to execute it.

I am using windows and I am not familiar with scripting.Can you guide me how and where to execute the command so that I can see the nodes and relationships created in Neo4j.

Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

On the Windows with the installer the shell is not officially installed.

See this blog post for an explanation: http://java.dzone.com/articles/solving-problems-neo4j-shell

```
C:\Program Files\Neo4j Community>jre\bin\java -cp bin\neo4j-desktop-2.0.0.jar org.neo4j.shell.StartClient
```

Btw. for other cool examples check out http://blog.bruggen.com